# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): illegal operation attempted on a revoked proxy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, easy-peasy

I'm using easy-peasy (redux based state management) and I don't know why I'm getting this error when I'm calling action method in useEffect in the below code:
**Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): illegal operation attempted on a revoked proxy**

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useStoreActions, useStoreState } from '../model/hooks';
import Crousels from './Crousels/Crousels';
import Footer from './Footer/Footer_';
import Collections from '../containers/Collections/Collections';

const Home = () => {
    
    const items = useStoreState(state => state.Collections.collections);
    const action = useStoreActions(actions => actions.Collections.fetchCollections);

    useEffect(() => {
        action();
    },[action]);

    return (
        <div>
            <Crousels />
            <Footer/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

When I'm consoling items, it returns me this:
Proxy { : null , : null }

Here is my collection model is defined

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { Action, action, thunk, Thunk } from 'easy-peasy';

interface Response {
    name : string;
    description : string;
}

interface Collections {
    isLoading : boolean;
    collections : Response[];
    error : string;
    fetchCollectionsRequest: Action<Collections>;
    fetchCollectionsSuccess: Action<Collections,Response[]>;
    fetchCollectionsFailure: Action<Collections,string>;
    fetchCollections : Thunk<Collections>;
    fetchCollectionList : Thunk<Collections,string>;
}

export interface StoreModel {
    Collections : Collections;
}

export const model : StoreModel= {
    Collections : {
        isLoading : false,
        collections : [],
        error : '',
        fetchCollectionsRequest : action( state => {
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading : true
            }
        }),
        fetchCollectionsSuccess : action( ( state, payload ) => {
            return {
                ...state,
                collections : payload,
                isLoading : false
            }
        }),
        fetchCollectionsFailure : action( ( state, payload ) => {
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading : false,
                error : payload
            }
        }),
        fetchCollections : thunk( actions => {
            actions.fetchCollectionsRequest();
            axios.get('/categories?filter={"where":{"isHidden":false}}')
                .then( res => {
                    const response = res.data.map( (d:any) => {
                        return {
                            name : d.name,
                            description : d.description
                        }
                    })
                    actions.fetchCollectionsSuccess(response)
                })
                .catch( err => actions.fetchCollectionsFailure(err.message));
        })
    }
}
```

Please someone point out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`easy-peasy` uses [`Immer`](https://github.com/immerjs/immer) internally, which allows you to mutate the state inside of an action:

```
        fetchCollectionsRequest : action( state => {
            state.isLoading = true;
        }),
        fetchCollectionsSuccess : action( ( state, payload ) => {
            state.isLoading = false;
            state.collections = payload;
        }),
        fetchCollectionsFailure : action( ( state, payload ) => {
            state.isLoading = false;
            state.error = payload;
        }),
```

If you don't want to write your actions this way (by mutating `state`), you can opt out of this approach. [This is stated in the docs](https://easy-peasy.now.sh/docs/api/action.html#switching-to-an-immutable-api):

> By default we use immer to provide a mutation based API.
> This is completely optional, you can instead return new state from your actions.
> Should you prefer this approach you can explicitly disable immer via the disable Immer configuration value of createStore.

```
const store = createStore(model, {
  disableImmer: true //  set the flag
})
```